# Keep-alive option in webpack-dev-server with http-proxy-middleware?

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server, keep-alive, http-proxy-middleware

We are using webpack-dev-server with http-proxy-middleware.  Our Protractor test cases keep timing out.  I suspect we need to have keep-alive set to true, but I don't see such an option either in webpack-dev-server nor in http-proxy-middleware.  Is it possible to configure keep-alive for wepack-dev-server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can configure keep-alive in headers options like below.
Use devServer.proxy.headers option.

```
devServer: {
    publicPath: '...',
    contentBase: '...',
    port: 9090,
    proxy: {
        '/**': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            headers: {
                Connection: 'keep-alive'
            }
        }
    },
    open: true,
    inline: true,
    hot: false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `Connection: 'Keep-alive'`, Make sure the first letter 'C' captialized, not the `connection: 'keep-alive'` whick ruined my whole day.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but (assuming this is still an issue) this is a bug in webpack; HTTP headers are expected to be [case insensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers). On the off chance you can still reproduce this, it'd be great to file a bug against whichever layer is failing to process headers case-insensitively.